# Some shortcut not working at AndroidStudio in Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04, android-studio-2.3

My `AndroidStudio` version is 2.3.1 and my Keymaps is: Default for XWin

[image]

With this keymap the shortcut for `Find Usages` is `Alt + F7`
[image]
but it not work (so now if I need to find Find Usages I need right click at the method and click `Find Usages`)

Also the shortcut for Open Settings (`Ctrl+Alt+S`) not work too
[image]

How can I make it work? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find the reason for my problem, in `System->Shortcut` of my Ubuntu 14.04.
The `Alt+F7` is use for `Move Window` so when I use it in my AndroidStudio it not work. Therefore if I change it to another shortcut, `Alt+F7` will work at AndroidStudio

[image]

It same with `Ctrl+Alt+S` (`Ctrl+Alt+S` in `System->Shortcut` = Toogle shaded state)