# Project structure shortcut key not working in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Earlier even when coding if we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> it'll open the window. Now it's not working like the past. For opening the window i had to open File, and after that i need to press the shortcut key for working it.
I'm using Android Studio 3.5.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Docs says, it'll open up the project structure dialog by pressing shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> as given in [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts). But still, if you can't open that project structure window by shortcut, there should be an issue with your keybindings. Go to **Preferences > Keymap** and check for it or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and start typing the name of a command and it will show you all matching commands and their key bindings if they have one. That's really convenient for looking up the key shortcut for something if you have a hint of what it's called.

In most dialogs/windows there's a search box, and you can usually just start typing to start a search. It's especially good for preferences, where there are so many options that are hard to find.

As a quick fix, you can modify the key-binding for the project structure dialog as given in the screenshot.

[image: MacOS Android Studio Key-Binding]

Comment: hi @Kiran there is a shortcut that I used in java alot. Ctrl+Alt+F to make a variable a global variable. It does not work in kotlin how do I create it.

Comment: I guess you can't. But alternatively, you can use kotlin language custom snippet and expand it with pressing the TAB key. Which keymap you use?

Comment: If you want to create a snippet, go to `Preference > Editor > Live Templates > Kotlin` and press `+` button. enter abbreviation and template text. Now whenever you write abbreviation and press TAB in code, The abbreviation will be expanded to the template you defined.

Comment: which keymap? there is only one I see.. well I saw that ctrl+alt+f is called `extract field` inside main menu->code->refactor->extract in the keymap list. It is used to extract a local variable and make it into a field variable.\

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **3.5.1** Version of Android Studio and according to the official document, it shows exactly what are they written in doc.

Here is the official [DOC](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts)

According to the document Control+Alt+Shift+S, it shows me this [image: dialogue]

**Setting of Key Map**

[image]

Comment: However, this key map is not working, not only for me, here in my office i have checked over many systems, still this is not working, but Ctrl Alt S is working fine.

Comment: Which OS you're using right now? Have you seen this before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383539/some-shortcut-not-working-at-androidstudio-in-ubuntu

Comment: have you updated IDE and tools? https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update

Comment: Bro, i also checked support of Microsoft for windows 10, and i couldn't find this specific keymap is used for any other event, i hope this is something else @Tanveer Munir

Comment: @ManojPerumarath which KeyMap you're using? I update the answer please look.

Comment: hey guys...there is a shortcut that I used in java alot. Ctrl+Alt+F to make a variable a global variable. It does not work in kotlin how do I create it.

Comment: you shortcut key according to the document it seems like Extract Field if you want to use for another purpose override it.